# Dealing with special characters in SPARQL-Filter expressions

Tags: regex, sparql, dbpedia

I access the SPARQL-Endpoint of dbpedia[1] to get the URI for a given city. I use the following query to achieve this:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
select distinct * where 
  {?uri rdfs:label ?label. 
  FILTER (REGEX(STR(?label), "^Köln$", "i")). 
  ?uri a dbpedia:PopulatedPlace.
}
```

If I query for a city without a german umlaut, everything works fine, but if there is an umlaut, I get nothing. When executing this query via code, I even get a 406-error (not acceptable)

Any idea, how to deal with umlauts in a SPARQL-query against dbpedia?

Thanks in advance,
Frank

[1] http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: Have you tried using `^K.ln$` ?

Comment: "When executing this query via code, I even get a 406-error (not acceptable)"  This sounds like it might be more of an issue with the client encoding the query than the query itself.

Comment: Also, there's no real reason to do `FILTER (REGEX(STR(?label), "^Köln$", "i")). `  If you want to match an entire string case insensitively, just lowercase or uppercase both strings and compare equality.  Of course, in this case, it's unlikely that you really need the case insensitivity, and you might be better off just asking for `?uri rdfs:label "Köln"@de` (if that's the correct language tag).

Comment: @ Fede: This would work, but would also lead to unwanted hits like Kiln.
@JoshuaTaylor: Client encoding might be a problem in that case, but I still get no results from the endpoint over their webinterface. With ?uri rdfs:label "Köln"@de I get the expected result, but I cannot be sure, which language the given city name actually is, so I wanted to use a "language-insensitive" notation.

Comment: @Aaginor Well, rather than searching for "Köln"@de, you could search for things, and then filter those that have labels whose strings are "Köln" (or contain it).  The problem in that, of course, is that now there are *lots* of results to be considered and filtered.  That might not be a problem, since the `a PopulatedPlace` pattern will have narrowed down some of the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the handling of your character, maybe in transport, or otherwise. It does work when you just write it down in [unicode hex for ö](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96), like so:

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
select distinct * where 
  {?uri rdfs:label ?label. 
  FILTER (REGEX(STR(?label), "^K\u00F6ln$")). 
  ?uri a dbpedia:PopulatedPlace.
}
```

Edit: I see now that this isn't working with the 'i' flag. Documentation suggests the 'u' flag would be applicable here.

Comment: +1 for addressing the encoding issue.  I'd still point out that if the intent is to match the exact string, it could be less expensive to just normalize the case of both strings and compare for equality.

Comment: I only get results without any flag, but I think that's the best solution. Thanks for the answer!